# Remove the &nbsp; space from html

Tags: html, character-encoding, space

I am working with HTML, Javascript and jquery mobile. At the top of a lateral panel there is a  space caused by some `&nbsp;` characters. Is there a way to remove them directly from the HTML  code without using Javascript? I am using the UTF-8 charset but I will change it if it can solve the problem.

EDIT:
Here is the html I saved on the server:

```
<div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay" id="left-panel" data-theme="b">
.... html code ....
</div>
```

Here is the html generated by jquery mobile:

```
<div data-role="panel" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="overlay" id="left-panel" data-theme="b" class="ui-panel ui-panel-position-left ui-panel-display-overlay ui-body-b ui-panel-fixed ui-panel-animate ui-panel-open">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <div class="ui-panel-inner">
        .... html code ....
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with character sets, instead you should provide the HTML where the additional space occurs. If a browser cares about whitespace and how depends on the HTML and the context of the whitespace.

Comment: Select the offending character, then pressing "Delete"? It has nothing to do with how you saved your document.

Comment: I edited the post with the code, hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the `&nbsp` from your code. That's it.

Comment: There's none. I didn't write it!?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen to me. I'm guessing that you copied code from their "View Source" examples. Apparently when you copy from that it has a bunch of spaces rather than tabs for formatting. If you remove all the excess spaces it should work fine. This happened to me using Sublime Text 2.